# Error using laravel localhost:8000 facebook Can't Load URL appdomain facebook login

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I've seen a couple posts about this and blogs about this.  I've tried their solutions and still running into the dreaded:

"Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings."

Some answers have said you need to add a platform in settings => basic and put the localhost address in there...

so..

[image]

Still get the error...

And other answers say you need to also have it set in the app domains on the same window.  So, I put in "http://localhost:8000/" save it and it saves as:

[image]

And I still get the "can't load url..."

My host file has:

[image]

I'm starting to feel like this has been so difficult that the answer has to be something so simple.  But how the heck do you setup the facebook details for local development/testing??

Every answer I'm finding seems to revolve around those 2 input fields within the facebook setup.

The url I'm on when I'm trying to call it is "http://127.0.0.1:8000/login".  I'm trying to access it using the javascript sdk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was typing that last sentence, with the idea that the answer was most likely a simple one I decided to try another solution.

I changed "http://127.0.0.1:8000/login" in my browser window to "http://localhost:8000/login"

And it fixed my problem.   There goes several hours of my life, so hopefully this will help somebody else.